# Removing first value from a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

My website shows recommend pages for users. Right now, I suppose to send a query to get a URL addresses. It will be annoying to my server to get every single URL addresses. So, I would like to get 5 URL addresses from db and store them in to session as array.

```
array (
  url[0] => google.com/1
  url[1] => google.com/2
  url[2] => google.com/3
  url[3] => google.com/4
  url[4] => google.com/5
)
```

It would like to store like this, and I would like to remove the first value after a user visits.

```
array (
  url[0] => google.com/2
  url[1] => google.com/3
  url[2] => google.com/4
  url[3] => google.com/5
)
```

It will be like this after first step.

```
array (
  url[0] => google.com/5
)
```

At the end, there will be only one left in the session. After this, the server will send a query to get 5 different URL addresses. So, can you give me an idea how to set this up?

Comment: What you are looking is `array_shift()`. And it's a RTFM-question .. not really fit for SO.

Comment: It's not only RTFM question - there is also a question of logic involved here which is not obvious. For example, how to test which url a user clicked. How and when to test if SESSION has urls, and how to remove selected url. Then, how and when to make sql query for 5 urls and how to add them to SESSION. And how to display those urls properly. These are not so obvious issues for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Example use:

```
$array = array("google.com/1", "google.com/2", "google.com/3");
array_shift($array);
print_r($array);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => google.com/2
    [1] => google.com/3
)
```

Comment: why negative marks on this answer, it seems a perfect one ?

Comment: Guessing you were downvoted because you answered several minutes after the first answers were posted

Comment: @MarkBaker several? 3 minutes...the other answers were posted while I was writing, so thought I may as well post it. Not that I'm really bothered, but someone seems to have downvoted all the answers on this question.

Comment: @Nick - yeah, true... I was trying to think of a valid reason, but even Evert and gintas have been downvoted.... so I guess it's just one of the occasional downvoting idiots that's gone on a rampage

Comment: Nick, don't worry. Your answer was perfect for me. I picked your answer as best answer :) have a great day

Comment: @Jake haha, wasn't worried =D just pointing out that someone had down voted everyone :/ thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`array_shift` function](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

> *Shift[s] an element off the beginning of array*

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

```
$array = array (
  0 => google.com/1
  1 => google.com/2
  2 => google.com/3
  3 => google.com/4
  4 => google.com/5
)
```

If you do

```
$url = array_shift($array);
```

`$url` will be set to google.com/1 and `$array` will become

```
$array = array (
  0 => google.com/2
  1 => google.com/3
  2 => google.com/4
  3 => google.com/5
)
```