# func_num_args get rid of the first value

Tags: php, mysqli

hi I what to get rid of one of the value in side func_num_args I already formatting it but first  value I do not need here my code

thank

```
    [1] => 14 [2] => user_id [3] => username [4] => password [5] => first_name [6] => last_name [7] => email [8] => type )

     function user_data($con,$user_id)
    {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bear") or die ($connect_error);
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    print_r ($func_get_args);
    if ($func_num_args > 1)
    {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `' , $func_get_args) . '`';
    //$fields = substr($fields, 4);
    echo $fields;

    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));
    return $data;
    print_r($data);
    }
```

i need to get rid of it as put the formatted func_num_args in to $field variable and then passing it on to a mysqli statement

i could substr but the amount  need to substr will change for each user

Comment: Take a look at the PHP documentation of [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) is the one you need but there are some others that could help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904008/removing-first-value-from-a-php-array